# Can't obtain first dropdown value (but gets the rest)

Tags: php, arrays, wpbakery

I'm building a custom element in `wp-bakery` and having mixed results with a dropdown field.

**The field:**

```
array(
    'type' => 'dropdown',
    'heading' => __("Text align"),
    'param_name' => 'text_align',
    'description' => 'Select the alignment of the text.',
    'value' => array(
        'Left' => 'left',
        'Center' => 'center',
        'Right' => 'right'
    ),
    'std' => 'left',
    'admin_label' => false,
    'group' => __('Content', 'my-text-domain'),
)
```

**How I'm displaying the field:**

```
<div text-<?php echo $text_align; ?>>
```

**The results:**

- Selecting "Left" from dropdown: Outputs `text-`
- Selecting "Center" from dropdown: Outputs `text-center`
- Selecting "Right" from dropdown: Outputs `text-right`

Unsure why left is the only one that doesn't work?

**var_dump results:**

- `var_dump` with "Left" as the dropdown option: string(0) ""
- `var_dump` with "Center" as the dropdown option: string(6) "center"
- `var_dump` with "Right" as the dropdown option: string(5) "right"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://urosevic.net/wordpress/tips/dropdown-defaults-visual-composer/), the `std` of the default value in `wp-bakery` should be the name (key) of the array value. So you need to have:

```
...
'value' => array(
    'Left' => 'left',
    'Center' => 'center',
    'Right' => 'right'
),
'std' => 'Left', // Notice the capital L
...
```

Comment: ah damn, I'm pretty sure I tried that, guess my page was still cached. Nevertheless, it's working now. Thank you :)